# Не работает С-ный код на AVR Atmega 8515

Tags: avr, avr-gcc

Новичок в программирование МК.
Использую AtmelStudio 7.Не пойму почему не работает код на Atmega8515 (код ниже).
На PD4 висит светодиод, который подключен анодом на +5. По моему разумению светодиод должен мигать. А он при подаче питания зажигается через какое то время. По ощущениям как будто прерывание срабатывает 1 раз.
Если раскомментировать строчку в обработчике и закомментировать ифчики в while, то светодиод постоянно мигает, как и ожидалось.
Прошу помочь! Спасибо!

PS Пересмотрел кучу подобных примеров. Есть подозрения, что "volatile" игнорируется компилятором. Может быть настройка IDE?

```
#define F_CPU 16000000UL
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

volatile int flag = 0;

int main(void)
{
    DDRD = 1 << (PD4);
    PORTD = 1 << PD4;
    TCCR1B = 1 << (CS12);
    TIMSK |= 1 << (TOIE1);
    sei();
    while(1)
    {
        if (flag == 0)
        {
            PORTD = 1 << PD4;
        }
         
        if (flag == 1)
        {
            PORTD = 0 << PD4;
        }
    }
}

ISR(TIMER1_OVF_vect)
{
    cli();
    
    //PORTD ^= 1<<(PD4);
    
    if (flag == 1)
    {
        flag = 0;
    }
    
    if (flag == 0)
    {
        flag = 1;
    }
    
    sei();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

попробуй примерно так.

```
#define F_CPU 16000000UL
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <avr/delay.h>

volatile int flag = 0;

int main(void)
{
    DDRD = 1 << (PD4);
    PORTD = 1 << PD4;
    TCCR1B = 1 << (CS12);
    TIMSK |= 1 << (TOIE1);
    sei();
    while(1)
    {
        if (flag)
        {
            PORTD ^= 1<<(PD4);
            flag = 0;
        }
        else
            _delay_ms(1);
    }
}

ISR(TIMER1_OVF_vect)
{
    flag = 1;
}
```

Comment: Да ваш код заработал! Спасибо!

Comment: Здорово помогли. Свой переделал следующим образом: отдельные ифчики обработчика заменил на конструкцию if-else и все заработало! Потом не успокоился и добавил еще несколько else if (){} в середину и все работает! Хотя в функции main остались отдельные ифчики. Объясните plz почему так происходит? PS ассемблером не занимался около 10 лет - сам глянуть не смогу уже, что там на самом деле на выходе.

Comment: код внутри прерывания должен быть минимальной длины. основная обработка должна быть в цикле без прерываний. Если долго работающий код у вас будет выполнятся в прерывании, то есть риск что другие прерывания мк не обработает в этот момент, когда происходит "прерывание" мк откладывает текущий код, запоминает адрес и часть регистров и вызывает процедуру из таблицы прерываний, количество и область памяти под эти регистры у него не безгранична, поэтому нужно стараться минимизировать код прерывания чтобы мк вернулся к выполнению основного цикла как можно раньше.

Comment: У меня прерывание было только одно разрешено и новый код обработчика куда больше изначального.

Comment: если у вас одно прерывание, и оно обработается раньше чем таймер вызовет повторное, то да не столь критично. это просто общая рекомендация по дизайну обработчиков у 8ми битных авров. Для учебно тестовых целей думаю размер обработчика не столь принципиален, но предположим вы захотите добавить еще нажатие кнопки и обработку по прерыванию, или например USB-hid эмуляцию софтовую, и тут уже пару лишних ненужных операций внутри обработчика вам могут нарушить работу т.к. прерывания будут частые, и у них есть приоритет, если вы напишите много кода в более приоритетном, тогда другой код не сработает

Comment: Я это все понимаю, мне непонятно, почему конкретно первый вариант кода не работал, а по большому счету тоже самое немного переписанное заработало?

Comment: Два отдельных ифчика не работали, а конструкция if-else заработала. Больше ничего не делал. проверено неоднократно.

Comment: блин а что ты хотел у тебя же всегда одно значение у флага без "иначе"  первое условие присваивало флаг = 0, второе всегда(потому что флаг был = 0 в прошлом условии) присваивало единицу. и так в вечном цикле.

Comment: запиши ты flag = !flag; вместо двух условий и все бы заработало.

Comment: Да! Стыдно! )))) Нужно было в каждом ифчике return ставить тогда. Глаз совсем замылился) Спасибо!